# Implementing multiple gestures on gridView android

Tags: android, dynamicgridview

I want to implement the following gestures on my grid view:

1. Drag items to rearrange them.
2. Allow multiple selection on items.
3. Perform some action when a single item is clicked.

For case one, I'm trying to use this library: 
https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

However, when I'm using this dynamicGridView instead of the android provided `GridView`, this dynamic `GridView` is not allowing me to select multiple items.

Can someone please help me use this library, while allowing me to select multiple items as in Android's `GridView`.

Comment: You have to be aware that multiple selection will only be possible if drag mode is off